# laravel4 get last insert id outside of model

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I am uploading an image and returning json array with image data such as width, size, etc.

```
    $json = ImageUpload::handle(Input::file('filedata'));
    if ($json !== false) {
         $this->imageModel->create($this->user, $json);
        return Response::json($json, 200);
    }
```

Now this create method just inserts new data into the database via laravel eloquent model. I can't think of a way, to insert the data, return the id of just inserted data and somehow merge json array and return it with other json data? Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can`t you do this?

```
$json = ImageUpload::handle(Input::file('filedata'));

if ($json !== false) 
{
   $image = $this->imageModel->create($this->user, $json);

   $json = ['image_id' => $image->id, 'upload' => $json];

   return Response::json($json, 200);
}
```

EDIT:

Also, what is this method?

```
$this->imageModel->create($this->user, $json);
```

An Eloquent create() or a repository or something else? If this is Eloquent, you probably have a problem in this method because create accepts an array as parameter and it should be:

```
$this->imageModel->create(['user' => $user, 'json' => $json]);
```

Comment: Well, I have tried a similar thing.Might sound stupid but I always get an error that I'm trying to get a property of non object..

EDIT, just realised that I was returning bool in create method. I just returned the object and it works..:) thanks!!

Comment: You may have other problems in that code, check my edit.

Comment: P.S it was a repository but instead of returning object I was returning save() method:) Thanks very much again.